# Drawing tree diagrams of ambiguous sentences generated by a CFG

Tags: syntax, grammar, syntax-trees, phrase-structure, conjunctions

Suppose I have the following CFG rules:

```
S -> NP VP
NP -> (D) NOM
VP -> V (NP) (NP)
NOM -> N
NOM -> NOM PP
VP -> VP PP
PP -> P NP
X -> X+ CONJ X
```

How should I draw the tree diagram of this sentence?

`Most cats and dogs with fleas live in the neighbourhood.`

As I understand it, the sentence has two different interpretations, with one attributing `fleas` to both `cats` and `dogs` and the other only to `dogs`.

For the case of attributing `fleas` to only dogs I drew the following diagram:

[image]

Now for the second interpretation, I figured I should add the NOM substructure to the first NOM before CONJ:

[image]

This seems to be correct to me, because it reflects the fact that the attribute is equally applicable to both NOMs. But on the other hand, I am writing words on the added branch that aren't there (have been deleted for avoiding repetition) and the tree reads a longer sentence.

Is my parsing correct and if not how should I make it work right?

Comment: What is the definition of a tree diagram. I know of parse trees, corresponding to the analysis of a sentence according to the rules of a grammar and I can tell you about that. But I do not know what you call tree diagrams, and hence I cannot tell how to get them from parse trees... Unless you provide the definition.

Comment: The rule `X -> X+ CONJ X` is not a standard CF rule, for 2 reasons. I
guess the `+` means arbitrary repetition with at least one occurrence.
Also I suppose it is actually a rule schema, where `X` stands for any
non-terminal, but the same for a whole rule instance (which may
produce some strange sentences if you replace `X` by `CONJ`).  Am I
correct?

Comment: Why do you have a rule `NOM -> N`, but `N` does not appear in your trees?

Comment: This is probably not a standard CFG rule, right. It is taken from an example in the first chapters of a book on HPSG theory by Ivan Sag, where the author is still explaining how CFG's work before starting to really define HPSG itself. + is indeed a Kleene plus and yes I should have added `N` to the last branches of both diagrams, I simply forgot that.

Comment: Thanks. And what are tree diagrams? Are they supposed to be parse trees?

Comment: Here I am mostly interested in seeing how one would attribute the part `with fleas` with the conjoined parts. I am not sure how one would show the different interpretations of an ambiguous sentence using a simple diagram like this which uses CFG rules (I know the rules might not be strictly correct)

Comment: Yes, they are tree diagrams that are supposed to parse the sentence according to the rules.

Comment: For future you may wish to use the TikZ LaTeX package for drawing your trees.  Looks like you're using something like this: http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for parse trees according to your grammar, the
first tree seems correct, up to the missing `N` symbols, and a missing
`NOM` above `fleas`.

However your second diagram should look as follow, drawing only the
relevant part that changes (i.e. under NOM_1):

```
            NOM 1
         __/   \___
        /          \
     NOM            PP
    / | \_         /  \
   /  |   \       |    |
NOM  CONJ  NOM    P    NP
 |     |    |     |    |
 N    and   N   with  NOM
 |          |          |
cats       dogs        N
                       |
                     fleas
```

Now, If you wanted to draw both trees in a single diagram, that is
possible, but significantly more complicated. But I doubt your book does anything of the kind.